# Get all extensions and their respective file count in a directory

Tags: linux, find, extension

Getting all extensions for a directory: easy. Getting file counts for a particular extension: easy.

But getting all file extensions and their respective file counts is alluding me.

eg.

```
+ dir
 + abc.txt
 + def.txt
 + abc.pdf
 * def.pov
```

should return something like:

```
.txt 2
.pdf 1
.pov 1
```

The aim of this exercise is that I want to find out which file extension is popular in a certain directory.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
/var/cache$ sudo find ./ -type f | grep -E ".*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" | sed -e 's/.*\(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\)$/\1/' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
      1 .6
      1 .cache
      1 .noconf
      1 .php
      1 .sl
      2 .bin
      2 .el
      2 .tdb
      4 .baseA
      4 .baseB
      4 .dat
      4 .DB
     27 .db
    221 .deb
```

Here is the explication:

```
find ./ -type f
```

find only file, not directory

```
grep -E ".*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
```

filter file with extension

```
sed -e 's/.*\(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\)$/\1/'
```

delete path and file name, save only extension

```
sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

sort, uniq and sort

Comment: You could make your regex allow more characters in the extension and eliminate `grep` by doing this: `sed -ne '/\.[^./]*$/s/.*\(\.[^.]*\)$/\1/p'`

Comment: Dennis, replacing the grep and sed with your sed returns the following error: sed: -e expression #1, char 30: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Linux (gnu grep), this is a good time to use Perl REs (PCRE) `-P` and grep's `-o` option. Taking @bindbn's answer as a great candidate:

```
find . -type f | grep -Po '\.([\w\d])*$' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and came up with this solution:

```
find . -type f | rev | cut -d "." -f 1 | rev | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

This is very similar to the other solutions proposed here, but perhaps easier to understand/remember and maybe slightly faster. It also avoids the usual headaches with filenames containing special characters.

`rev | cut -d "." -f 1 | rev` reverses the filename string, extracts the (reversed) file extension up to the "." delimiter, and reverses back the extension substring, then `sort | uniq -c | sort -n`  counts the instances of each extension and prints the result in ascending order of matches.