# Calculating total file size by extension in shell

Tags: filesystems, shell, disk-space-utilization

We have a set of directories containing lucene indexes. Each index is a mix of different file types (differentiated by extension) eg:

```
0/index/_2z6.frq
0/index/_2z6.fnm
..
1/index/_1sq.frq
1/index/_1sq.fnm
..
```

(it's about 10 different extensions)

We'd like to get a total by file extension, eg:

```
.frq     21234
.fnm     34757
..
```

I've tried various combinations of du/awk/xargs but finding it tricky to do exactly this.

Comment: You have the answer for that problem in this post :
http://serverfault.com/questions/183431/get-all-extensions-and-their-respective-file-count-in-a-directory

Comment: Do you want to know the total size of each type of file or the total number of each type of file ?

Comment: Total file size please.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For any given extension you an use

```
find /path -name '*.frq' -exec ls -l {} \; | awk '{ Total += $5} END { print Total }'
```

to get the total file size for that type.

And after some thinking

```
#!/bin/bash

ftypes=$(find . -type f | grep -E ".*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" | sed -e 's/.*\(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\)$/\1/' | sort | uniq)

for ft in $ftypes
do
    echo -n "$ft "
    find . -name "*${ft}" -exec ls -l {} \; | awk '{total += $5} END {print total}'
done
```

Which will output the size in bytes of each file type found.

Comment: Thanks, was looking for something that summarized by any extension (as it'd be handy to then sort for example)

Comment: Check my update.

Comment: great thanks. awk produces scientific output for some of the numbers, can this be disabled:
.fdt 3.15152e+10

Comment: slightly tweaked to just give plain integer numbers:
find . -name "*${ft}" -print0 | xargs -0 du -c | grep total | awk '{print $1}'

Comment: Might want to use `-iname` to make the file extenstion search case insensitive.

Comment: @barnybug: I don't have a version of awk that prints the total in scientific notation. What version/OS etc are you using ?

Comment: Ubuntu Lucid - it's just on the larger numbers (Gigabytes in size), perhaps over an int32.

Comment: Note that this script has horrible performance issues (still, I upvoted it). It scans input directory X times (where X is number of extensions found in the directory). If you need something faster check @glenn jackman answer

Answer (score 6):

With bash version4, you just need to call `find`, `ls` and `awk` not necessary:

```
declare -A ary

while IFS=$'\t' read name size; do 
  ext=${name##*.}
  ((ary[$ext] += size))
done < <(find . -type f  -printf "%f\t%s\n")

for key in "${!ary[@]}"; do 
  printf "%s\t%s\n" "$key" "${ary[$key]}"
done
```

Comment: This script doesn't not work well with file names with tab character. Changing `read name size` to `read size name` and `-printf "%f\t%s\n"` to `-printf "%s\t%f\n"`should fix it.

Comment: Note also that this script doesn't work well with files without extension. It will treat whole file name as extension. Add `if [ "$name" == "$ext" ]; then ext="*no_extension*"; fi` after `ext=${name##*.}` if you need to prevent it. This will put all files without extension into `*no_extension*` group (I'm using `*no_extension*` because `*` is not a valid character in file name)

Answer (score 4):

Every second column splited by `.` and last part (extension) saved in
array.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -printf "%s\t%f\n" | awk '
{
 split($2, ext, ".")
 e = ext[length(ext)]
 size[e] += $1
}

END{
 for(i in size)
   print size[i], i
}' | sort -n
```

then you got every extensions total size in bytes.

```
60055 gemspec
321991 txt
2075312 html
2745143 rb
13387264 gem
47196526 jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending on Iain's script with a faster version for working with a large number of files.

```
#!/bin/bash

ftypes=$(find . -type f | grep -E ".*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" | sed -e 's/.*\(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\)$/\1/' | sort | uniq)

for ft in $ftypes
do
    echo -ne "$ft\t"
    find . -name "*${ft}" -exec du -bcsh '{}' + | tail -1 | sed 's/\stotal//'
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution :

```
find . -type f | grep -E ".*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" | sed -e 's/.*\(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\)$/\1/' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Solution posted originally on this post : [Get all extensions and their respective file count in a directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/183431/get-all-extensions-and-their-respective-file-count-in-a-directory)

Comment: This is a count by number of files, not what I was asking - I'd like a total by size.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using this two commands:

```
FILES=$(find . -name '*.c')
stat -c %s ${FILES[@]} | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print ".c" " " sum }'
```

Answer (score 0):

my version of answer to the question:

```
#!/bin/bash

date >  get_size.log
# Lists all files
find . -type f -printf "%s\t%f\n" | grep -E ".*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" | sort -h | awk  '
{
        split($2, ext, ".")
        e = ext[length(ext)]
        # Checks that one extension could be found
        if(length(e) < length($2)) {
                # Check that file size are bigger than 0
                if($i > 0) {
                        # Check that extension not are integer
                        if(!(e ~/^[0-9]+$/)) {
                                size[e] += $1
                        }
                }
        }
        if(length(e) == length($2)) {
                size["blandat"] += $1
        }
}

END{
 for(i in size)
   print size[i], i
}' | sort -n >> get_size.log
echo
echo
echo The result are in file get_size.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Crab (http://etia.co.uk/) - it's a command-line utility that allows you to query the filesystem using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ft in $(find "$1/" -type f | { export GREP_OPTIONS="--color=never" && grep -E ".*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"; } | sed -E 's/.*(\.[^\.]*)$/\1/' | sort | uniq)
do
    find "$1/" -name "*$ft" -exec stat -f%z {} \; | awk '{total += $1} END {printf "%s\t",total}'
    echo " $ft"
done | sort -hr
```

```
$ bash temp.sh assets
1622995  .monstertype
1279175  .frames
756855   .npctype
706087   .projectile
573611   .head
```